# Playing sound when Player touches part

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this script

```
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;
 
 public class SoundPlayer : MonoBehaviour
 {
     public Transform Player;
     public AudioSource SoundThatPlayed;
 
     void OnTriggerEnter(Collider Player) => SoundThatPlayed.Play();
 }
```

It works perfectly, but the sound plays when ANYTHING touches the part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OnTriggerEnter fires when ANY collider enters the trigger.  You can check for a specific tag, component, name, layer, etc. to filter out the unwanted triggers.

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider)
{
    var playerScript = collider.GetComponent<Player>();
    if (playerScript)
    {
        // An object with the Player script on it entered the trigger
        //
    }

    var isPlayerByName = collider.name == "My Player Name";

    var isPlayerByTag = collider.tag == "My Player Tag";
}
```

Comment: Got this error: Assets\SoundPlayer.cs(12,50): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Player' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: That was an example of checking the object by component (script).  If you create a script Player.cs (as MonoBehaviour) and attach it to your player, it will work.  Note you will not need the other checks (isPlayerByName, isPlayerByTag) as those are just checks for specific name or tag.